# %d format specifier in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, string-formatting

Well, I have the following code:

```
{
    int alfa = CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(atan2(normalized.y, -normalized.x)) + 180;
    NSString * counting = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"fdfg%d.png", alfa];
}
```

`int alfa` brings a number between `0` and `360`.

What I am trying to achieve is that `counting` string value is equal to a image file, i have 360 image files, all with this format `"fdfg0000.png" "fdfg0024.png" "fdfg0360.png`", increasing from 0 to 360, and so on...

the `%d` operator is not reading the value, because all the zeros leading the file name are already outputted by the program that creates them, without a chance to modify them, I have renamed 360 files manually to this format : `"fdfg1.png"` `"fdfg24.png"` `"fdfg340.png"`, and thats the format that %d reads properly.

So my question is, is there anyway to read  all the four zeros that the original file includes in a operator function?

Or does anyone know a way to rename 360 files automatically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can do it: replace `%d` with `%04d` to insert leading zeros and make the total number of digits equal 4:

```
NSString * counting =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"fdfg%04d.png", alfa];
//                                                     ^^
//                                                     ||
//                                  Pad with zeros-----+|
//                          Total number of digits------+
```

For more information on the format specifiers, read documentation of [`printf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fprintf.html): format specifiers of `stringWithFormat:` are for the most part compatible with it.

Comment: Thanks, sorry about the duplicate, i could not find it before.

Answer (score 1):

> so my question is, is there anyway to read all the four zeros that the
>   original file includes in a operator function?

Use `%04d` as the format specifier to pad the number to 4 places with leading zeros:

```
NSString * counting =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"fdfg%04d.png", alfa];
```

The format specifiers used by NSString (and NSLog, etc.) are pretty much the same set of specifiers used in C with functions like `printf()` and `scanf()`, so there's plenty of advice on the net about how to use them to achieve the desired results. The main difference is that Objective-C uses `%@` as the format specifier for an Objective-C object.